# Python: How to find the non matching keys from two dictionaries & need to write in a file?

Tags: python

In python I have two dictionary which are present in a list. I need to find out the non matching keys & need to write in a file

I have tried with set & symmetric_difference concept. Now i got all the non matching key in a form of set. Now i don't know how to write in a file.

```
first = dict(a=1, b=2)
second = dict(b=0, c=3)
for i in range(1):
    diff = set(first) ^ set(second)
    print diff
    filename = "disk_output.txt"
    fo = open (filename, "a")
    fo.write(("\n==> %s" % key)
```

output should be in file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`writelines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) to write an iterable to your file :

```
with open (filename, "a") as f :
    f.writelines(map(lambda x:"==> {}\n".format(x),diff))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a set, you can use `dict.viewkeys` for python2 then just format the output however you want and write, also open the file once using `with` which will automatically close your file:

```
first = dict(a=1, b=2)
second = dict(b=0, c=3)
with open("disk_output.txt","w") as f:
    f.writelines("==>{}\n".format(k) for k in first.viewkeys() ^ second)
```

Just use `.keys` for python3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `file.writelines()` and a generator expression:

```
first = dict(a=1, b=2)
second = dict(b=0, c=3)

with open("disk_output.txt","w") as f:
    f.writelines("==> {}\n".format(k) for k in set(first) ^ set(second))
```

Contents of `disk_output.txt` file afterwards:

```
==> a
==> c
```